# OpenGL app not running in NVIDIA

Tags: nvidia, opengl

When I try loading my OpenGL app in my PC with NVIDIA card I get this error:

```
Could not set X locale modifiers
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

I used the command:

```
ldconfig -p | grep libGL
```

My output is as follows:

```
libGL.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/nvidia-367/libGL.so.1
libGL.so.1 (libc6) => /usr/lib32/nvidia-367/libGL.so.1
**libGL.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so
libGL.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/nvidia-367/libGL.so**
libGL.so (libc6) => /usr/lib32/nvidia-367/libGL.so
```

It can be seen that the lines 3 & 4, libGL.so (libc6, x86-64) has duplicate pointer. The 3rd line has to be removed.
My system libGL pointers:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 439972 Jul 12 11:04 /usr/lib32/nvidia-367/libGL.so.1.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 14 Aug 12 00:23 /usr/lib32/nvidia-367/libGL.so.1 -> libGL.so.1.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug 12 00:23 /usr/lib32/nvidia-367/libGL.so -> libGL.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 14 Jul 22 13:22 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 -> libGL.so.1.2.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 14 Jul 22 13:22 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so -> libGL.so.1.2.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 459392 Jul 22 13:22 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Jul 22 13:22 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so -> mesa/libGL.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 579760 Jul 12 11:07 /usr/lib/nvidia-367/libGL.so.1.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 14 Aug 12 00:23 /usr/lib/nvidia-367/libGL.so.1 -> libGL.so.1.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug 12 00:23 /usr/lib/nvidia-367/libGL.so -> libGL.so.1
```

As can be see some are libGL.so.1.2.0 points to mesa libGL.so. I tried creating the sublink :

```
ln -s /usr/lib/nvidia-367/libGL.so.1 /user/local/lib/libGL.so.1.2.0
```

But the permission is denied.
 Please help me in this regard.